# Duplicate of a deleted question?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

I asked a question then realized I gave it a wrong tag (hence few views).
In order to have views again I decided to delete the question and ask new one (same question).

But I got error that this new one was a duplicate of the deleted one. Is this expected/correct behavior?

Comment: Quite possible that the system detects duplicates for your own deleted questions. You're supposed to edit your question and correct the tags, instead of deleting and reposting.

Comment: @Stijn I thought by deleting and reposting I would get more views (I was wrong?).

Comment: Editing the question will also bump it again and give you new views.

Comment: Deleting + reposting is _not_ acceptable behaviour if your question hasn't received enough views. You should use bounties if your question hasn't received enough attention.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth You should read carefully I think it received small views because initially I put a wrong tag on it.

Comment: @Stijn Doesn't seem to hold true for this particular question. But maybe it is because of title :/

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I have. My comment stands.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth No it doesn't by mistakenly putting wrong tag I should not be penalized for having to wait 2 days before bounty is available.

Comment: You are note penalized. You edit the question with the correct tags and the question will be bumped, and exposed to the proper crowd. Deleting and reposting it is still not acceptable behavior.

Comment: [That's old thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7054/299295).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Deleting and re-posting is not the correct solution; in fact, it's undesirable behaviour on Stack Overflow in general.

The correct solution would be to edit your question to give it the proper tag. Editing counts as activity and thus bumps the question to the top of the question queue (to the home page), so it will have a new chance of being seen.

Comment: True, but in my experience, they still get many fewer views than a new question if the original question is more than a few hours old. The default sort on a tag list is by *Newest*, not by *Recently Active*, which means that the bumped question doesn't appear to most people.

Comment: *Recently Active* is also very noisy, so I don't use it.